# What's happening in the line of code?

Tags: java, cryptography, aes

What's happening in this line of code ?

```
SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
```

I specially don't understand getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1") part

Comment: This is a factory returning a factory object. WTF!

Comment: @Seth: It is a rather standard pattern to have a static factory method returning/creating instances. It really doesn't matter if the instance returned is a factory class or a some date formatter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This funky looking string defines the secret-key algorithm to be used.  It is:

```
PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1
PBKDF2 With Hmac SHA1
```

- the **PBKDF2** function (from PKCS#5 version 2.0)
- which will be using **SHA-1** **HMAC** for its pseudo-random number generator

**References**:
We find similar algorithm names in [**Java Crypto Extension Guide Appending A**](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/jce/JCERefGuide.html#AppA), somehow PKCS5 version 2 may not have been available/documented then (or indeed as suggested by brianegge, may be a matter of export restriction, a common issue with cryptographic items).
The algorithm name does show up in [RFC3962](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3962) (AES for Kerberos) which may not be the very application you have in mind, but defined, all the same)

Comment: It's a standard name in Java 6.

Answer (score 1):

Different distributions of Java contain different crypto.  This is due to export restrictions and patents.  The line of code is requesting a factory which can create that type of key.

Specifically, **PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1** constructs secret keys using the **Password-Based Key Derivation Function** function found in [PKCS5 v2.0](http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2127).

Answer (score 1):

"PBKDF2" is a function defined in [PKCS #5](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2898.html) used to derive key material from a password.

PBKDF2 requires a pseudo-random function, and in this case, a message authentication code based on  the SHA-1 hash is used—"HmacSHA1".

So, this line is creating a factory. The factory might produce `SecretKey` objects that can be used to key a `Cipher` instance for a symmetric encryption algorithm or a `Mac` algorithm. Or, it can be used to make a "transparent" specification of an existing `SecretKey`.

One important thing to note about PBKDF2 is that it doesn't produce secret keys for any particular algorithm. It's a deterministic way to generate key "material" from a seed (a password), in such a way that the seed cannot be recovered from the generated key. Once the required number of bytes are generated, they are usually wrapped in a `SecretKeySpec` with the correct algorithm name.

You can see other standard names for secret key factories in the Java Crypto Architecture [Standard Names](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#SecretKeyFactory) documentation.